# cbind replaces String with number?

Tags: r, vector, matrix, cbind

```
x = iris$Sepal.Width;
y = iris$Species;

m = cbind(x,y);
```

the output of m is:

```
        x  y
  [1,] 3.5 1
  [2,] 3.0 1
  [3,] 3.2 1
  [4,] 3.1 1
  [5,] 3.6 1
  [6,] 3.9 1
```

but I want 'setosa', etc in column y instead of a number

how can I do that?

I want to combine the 2 Vectors because I want to filter afterwards with

```
m[m[,"y"]=="virginica",]
```

or is ther another oportunity to do that without cbind?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For `vectors` being combined with `cbind`, the result would be a `matrix`, which can only hold one type of data. Thus, the "Species" factor gets coerced to its underlying numeric value.

Try `cbind.data.frame` instead (or just `data.frame`) if you need your columns to have different data types.

```
> head(data.frame(x, y))
    x      y
1 3.5 setosa
2 3.0 setosa
3 3.2 setosa
4 3.1 setosa
5 3.6 setosa
6 3.9 setosa
> head(cbind.data.frame(x, y))
    x      y
1 3.5 setosa
2 3.0 setosa
3 3.2 setosa
4 3.1 setosa
5 3.6 setosa
6 3.9 setosa
```

Comment: I wonder, is there any use for `cbind.data.frame` over `data.frame` (i guess it's more explicit...)

Comment: just glanced at the `cbind.data.frame` code, and indeed it is basically just a wrapper for `data.frame`, with the addition of the `deparse.level` argument, see `?cbind.data.frame`

Answer (score 1):

`cbind()` returns a `matrix` which has to be of a single class. In this case everything is converted to `character` because that is the most general class (you can express numbers as characters but not the other way around). R relies on `data.frame` to store columns of different classes.

To do what you want you can either explicitly create a new `data.frame` or use a subset of the current one:

```
iris2 <- data.frame(x=iris$Sepal.Width, y=iris$Species)  ## creates new data.frame
iris[, c("Sepal.Width", "Species")   ## returns subset of iris
```

If you post the problem you are trying to solve there may be a more streamlined way to do the filtering you want.

Comment: I have a vector x and y where x holds data and y are classes. I want to seperate x into subvectors for each class

Comment: Take a look at `split()` to generate a list of `data.frame` objects, or functions like `tapply()` to apply a function to each subset. There are more efficient methods too, but these should get you on your way. Google "split-apply-combine with R".