# R: "cbind" doesn't use labels defined in "cut"

Tags: r

I created a vector, `marks`:

```
marks <- cut(scores[,1], breaks = break_vector, labels = mark_vector, right = FALSE)
```

Calling `marks` gives: `[1] 3 2 4 4 2 5 2 1`

That’s fine. Now I want to create a matrix, having `scores` in the first, and `marks` in the second column.

Then I use `marks_column <- cbind(marks)` before creating that matrix. There is the problem: In the output of R I now get a column, ignoring the `labels = mark_vector` from the cut function above. So the R output gives a column, as if I had written `labels = FALSE` insted of `labels = mark_vector`.

How can I fix that?

Comment: `cbind` coerces to a matrix, and as the results oc `cut` is a factor, it coerces to the levels of the factor ie 1,2,3 . So either use a dataframe to store your cut vector or set convert it to a character before using cbind.

Comment: @user20650 I think that'll work as an answer!

Comment: `cbind.data.frame(cut(rnorm(100), 6))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cbind returns index of factor vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24866356/cbind-returns-index-of-factor-vector) ; also relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23567625/cbind-replaces-string-with-number

Comment: @MichaelChirico ;cheers, though  probably best to mark it as a duplicate